# how to call one xml design into another xml design with using inflater in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

Is this possible or not in android?

I have one `xml` design1 file this file i want to add another `xml` design2..(i.e)

the first `xml` is one of the part in second `xml` design2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For including an XML layout in another XML layout file, you should use the `include` keyword

```
<include layout="@layout/you_xml_layout_name" />
```

For including an XML layout file programatically, you can use [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, yes.  Usually you will only want to do this for dynamic content, such as the list items inside a ListView or a GridView.

If you just want static content that you can re-use in multiple activity layouts, you may want to use the 'include' tag in your layouts instead.

Answer (score 0):

please Include layout in your xml

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/viewgroup_bottom_bar" /> // please set proper layout name in your layout folder
```